# excel vba format date with slashes as typed in cell?

Tags: excel, vba, date

Users can enter a date in column B freely like so:

(Dates in uk format)
Column B

```
02/01/2017
02.01.2017
01.01.17
01012017
010117
```

Its extremely frustrating when we want to run a report that these date formats are not consistent.

I am trying to create a code which will format the date, however it's entered with slashes like so:

```
02/01/2017
02/01/2017
01/01/2017
01/01/2017
etc...
```

Here is my code:

```
Dim Cell As Range, CellVal As String
  If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then
      For Each Cell In Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns("B"))
          CellVal = Cell.Value
          If (Not CellVal Like "*[!0-9]*") And (Len(CellVal) > 4) Then
              CellVal = Format(CellVal, "@@ @@ @@")
              Cell.Value = CDate(WorksheetFunction.Replace(CellVal, 4, 2, MonthName(Mid(CellVal, 4, 2))))
              Cell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
          End If
      Next Cell
  End If
```

This only seems to work if the user enters a 9 digit format like so:

```
01012017
```

This is then changed to

```
   01/01/2017
```

But if the user enters

```
010117
```

Then this translates to:

```
28/01/1955   <---This is wrong
```

The other thing, users may enter dots:

```
01.01.2017
```

Then the code just doesn't work at all.

Please can someone show me a better way to do this?

Comment: I assume that this is part of an **Event** macro......if this is true then format the entire column as *Text* **before** entering any data into it.  Your problem may be that Excel formats the data prior to the Event macro getting to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it simple and obvious...No?

```
Dim Cell As Range, CellVal As String, dim Dt as Date
  If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then
      For Each Cell In Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Columns("B"))
          val = Cell.Value

          if instr(val,".")>0 then 'check if this particular char is present
            temp = split(val,".")
            day= temp(0)
            month=temp(1)
            year=temp(2)
            Dt = DateSerial(year, month, day)
            Cell.Value= Format(Dt, "dd/mm/yy") 'you can change this to "dd-mmm-yyyy" or whatever
         else if instr(val,"/")>0 then
            temp =  Split(val,"/")
            day= temp(0)
            month=temp(1)
            year=temp(2)
            Dt = DateSerial(year, month, day)
            Cell.Value= Format(Dt, "dd/mm/yy")
         else if len(val) = 8 then
            day = left(val,2) ' start at first, and take 2
            month = mid(val, 3,2) 'start a 3rd char and take 2
            year = right(val,4)
            Dt = DateSerial(year, month, day)
            Cell.Value= Format(Dt, "dd/mm/yy")
         else if len(val) = 6 then
            day = left(val,2) ' start at first, and take 2
            month = mid(val, 3,2) 'start a 3rd char and take 2
            year = right(val,2)
            year = year +2000
            Dt = DateSerial(year, month, day)
            Cell.Value= Format(Dt, "dd/mm/yy")
         end if
      Next Cell
  End If
```

I could have make some mistakes in func. parameters here, because it's 1:30 in the morning, and I dont have excel at my laptop, but I think I got right the main part :)